# jquery load(): loading a javascript in to div, calls a function multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main div called #Content and I replace a data in the #Content based the menu item clicked:

here is the code:

```
$('.nav-button').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: I just played around with the sample site - but didn't dive into the code. The behavior we see here is your click event is being added more than once. Look into that, and try using $('.nav-button').unbind('click'); right before you assign the click event.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work out @Gallen

Comment: It'll work - follow Drew's advice for both of your click events. He's just elaborating on my suggestion.

Comment: @Gallen Yea i followed his code and made the changes, please check. But still no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer here:http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-load-loading-a-javascript-in-to-div-calls-a-function-multiple-times

just made a check not to load the script if it is loaded previously. using this simple script:

```
if (! window.loadedThisScript){
window.loadedThisScript = true
// the whole part of the script that you only want to load one time.
}
```

credit to: http://forum.jquery.com/user/jakecigar

Comment: Cool, make sure you accept your own answer - sorry I didn't get back to you last night.

Answer (score 2):

You're running this binding statement every time you click "Transport":

```
$(".tsave").live('click',function() {
```

Try changing it to this:

```
$(".tsave").unbind('click');
$(".tsave").live('click',function() {
```

jQuery will append binding statements every time you call them - so, if you bind a click event 10 times to one object, it will run that event 10 times on the event.

Also change this:

```
$(".save").live('click',function() {
```

To:

```
$(".save").unbind('click'); 
$(".save").live('click',function() {
```

Comment: Hmm - just checked your code, doesn't look like the unbind function is there... Where did you change it? Should be changed on scripts/tran-sheet/data_script.js

Comment: @sukarno a comment like "no use" is not only useless, it's also rude. You should always explain how you tried it and what happened, error messages.

Comment: I changed the code exactly in the same location u mentioned please check in firebug

Comment: Sorry for that but i double checked now!

Comment: Looks like you have 2 click events - I think you might use the second one instead of the one I provided above. I've edited the answer to have the second click statement you'll need to unbind for.

Comment: Actually  changed both, and for your information each one is a called on different events. .save is for the newly added row.

Comment: Well, the problem definitely exists because you're binding the click event to each of those 'save' links when you're loading in the content window. Binding a click event to something multiple times doesn't do an override, it just keeps accumulating them and will run them all on the click event. I would walk through your scripts and make sure you're not binding the click events multiple times.

Comment: Thanks! I do agree that it would be a binding issue and I also checked in fire bug the script is  being loaded multiple times when we keep clicking the transport.

Comment: Is there a better way to bind the java script to the content in the div, so that it will not load multiple times.

Comment: Yes. If Drew doesn't get to it before I do - I'll have a closer look at your code and type up an answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks drew and Gallen for your support, just found the answer